# How to extract Dates from "pandas.core.series.Series"?

Tags: python, pandas

I have difficulty extracting the Date column from "pandas.core.series.Series".

Here is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf
msft = yf.Ticker("GOOG")
print(msft.history(period = "max"))
```

Output:

```
               Open     High      Low  ...     Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                   ...                                    
2004-08-19    49.81    51.84    47.80  ...   44871300          0           0.0
2004-08-20    50.32    54.34    50.06  ...   22942800          0           0.0
2004-08-23    55.17    56.53    54.32  ...   18342800          0           0.0
2004-08-24    55.41    55.59    51.59  ...   15319700          0           0.0
2004-08-25    52.28    53.80    51.75  ...    9232100          0           0.0
...             ...      ...      ...  ...        ...        ...           ...
2019-10-28  1275.45  1299.31  1272.54  ...    2613200          0           0.0
2019-10-29  1276.23  1281.59  1257.21  ...    1869200          0           0.0
2019-10-30  1252.97  1269.36  1252.00  ...    1407700          0           0.0
2019-10-31  1261.28  1267.67  1250.84  ...  145470000          0           0.0
2019-11-01  1265.00  1274.62  1260.50  ...    1669400          0           0.0
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

```
Date                                 
2004-08-19
2004-08-20
2004-08-23
2004-08-24
2004-08-25
2019-10-28
2019-10-29
2019-10-30
2019-10-31
2019-11-01
```

I have tried researching and found a few ideas:

```
pandas.Series.str.extract
```

and found a similar question

[Extract date from pandas.core.series.Series in pandas dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55357264/extract-date-from-pandas-core-series-series-in-pandas-dataframe-columns?rq=1)

But as a beginner, I still do not understand the supposed solutions.

Comment: What happens when you try 'pandas.Series.str.extract'? What is your error message?

Comment: @powerPixie `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'` am I doing it the correct way? probably not. As I said, I am a beginner... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first save the complete history as a dataframe, you can then extract the index to a new dataframe:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd 
msft = yf.Ticker("GOOG")
df1 = msft.history(period="max")
print(df1)
```

This will output the same as your example, but now saved in a dataframe. Next:

```
date = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'])
date['date'] = df1.index.copy()
date
```

Output:

> ```
>   date
> 0 2004-08-19
> 1 2004-08-20
> 2 2004-08-23
> 3 2004-08-24
> 4 2004-08-25
> ...   ...
> 3824  2019-10-28
> 3825  2019-10-29
> 3826  2019-10-30
> 3827  2019-10-31
> 3828  2019-11-01
> ```